# Python: Compare sliced string to another string with "=="

Tags: python

I thought that the following would return `True` but that was not the case.

```
"Hey guys"[:4] == "Hey"
```

Printing both `"Hey guys"[:4]` and `"Hey"` prints out `Hey`. So I don't understand why would it be `False` under the `==` operator.

Comment: `[:4]` slice includes a space.

Comment: `print("*" + "Hey guys"[:4] + "*")` would have given you the answer.

Comment: When you slice the string `"Hey guys"[:4]` this will lead it to be `"Hey "` with a space trailing it. This is not the same as `"Hey"`

Comment: I'm wondering what you were expecting to get from this question... a minute amount of debugging would've helped you figure things out.

Comment: It is `"Hey guys"[:3]`. It prints a space, but you probably do not see that in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"Hey guys"[:4]` means you want the first 4 characters of `"Hey guys"` which includes the space. You only want the first 3 characters so it should be `"Hey guys"[:3]`.